# Can not get the language in phonegap cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Get the language in call back alert. but in the next line this shows undefined. See the code below.

```
 app.initialize();
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   function onDeviceReady() {
                var lang; 
                navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function (language) {lang =language.value;alert(lang);}); 
                alert(lang);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Prosun: getPreferredLanguage is function returns a success or failure response. In the above code, only the success handler is written.

The callbacks are asynchronous. So you will always receive undefined in the alert at line no 6.

Comment: Thanks, Then in which way i can get the device language in a variable for later use in this page?